# Quill custom blots: how to make Quill accept "incoming" custom code

Tags: quill, parchment

I'm using Quill in a project where I need make Quill "understands" some custom code when it initializes and when the editor's content is updated from the API.

To keep it symple: lets say I have a database where I have, for example, a field with this content:

`<p>Text</p><hr>`

On page loading, during Quill'a initialization, I need my 
Quill editor's container "accepts" this **incoming** code but Quill eliminates the `<hr>` tag.

Reading this guide ([Cloning Medium with Parchment](https://quilljs.com/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment/)) I understood how to create a new Quill's blot and how to add a custom control button in the toolbar to insert the custom blot (lets say the `<hr>` tag) in my Quill's editor.
Lets call this the "**outcoming** flow" which I think I get it.

Unfortunately If I save the updated content (lets say `<p>Text></p><hr>`) in the db, refreshing the page (I'm working with PHP) the `<hr>` tag is not kept but is "stripped away"...
I'm reading [Parchment documentation](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/) and I think I should make Parchment "accepts" the new blot (am I right?) but I'm not understanding how...

Here is a symple example: [Custom line blot example](https://codepen.io/Bissoli/pen/VqYvea).
You can see the "insert line" button is working ("*outcoming flow*" ok) but on page loading the `<hr>` tag is stripped away ("*incoming flow*" not ok).

I hope the explanation is clear ^^
Thanks for anyone is going to help me... ^^